# How to get table content using either apps script or importxml?

Tags: google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets

I've been trying to get the information below, using the formula below, but it shows as loading indefinitely:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&A5&"","table",INDEX(6,1)),3,1),"",FALSE,TRUE)
```

Since I got like over a thousand rows, I'm not sure that this calling this importHtml that many times will work...

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The values Energy | Oil & Gas E&P | USA is the one I'm trying to get!

Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvubH.png

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of "A5"?

Comment: Yes, @Tanaike! This is "MIME"! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot find the values of `Energy | Oil & Gas E&P | USA` from the HTML of the URL of `https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=MIME`. I apologize for this.

Comment: Could you please try it with "OVV" as the value, @Tanaike?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? About `Since I got like over a thousand rows, I'm not sure that this calling this importHtml that many times will work...`, I'm not sure whether above samples can be used for your situation. So, when my answer cannot be used for your situation, I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `Energy | Oil & Gas E&P | USA` from `https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=OVV`.
- You want to retrieve the values of `Technology | Software - Infrastructure | United Kingdom` from `https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=MIME`.
- You want to achieve this using IMPORTXML and Google Apps Script.

### Sample formula:

#### Sample xpath:

```
//div[@class='content']//table[1]//td[@class='fullview-links']
```

#### Sample formula:

```
=JOIN("",IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='content']//table[1]//td[@class='fullview-links']"))
```

- In this case, the URL is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

### Sample script:

In this script, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And please put the custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=OVV")` to a cell. By this, the script is run.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const content = res.match(/<div class\="content">[\s\S\w]+?<\/div>/g);
  if (content) {
    const table = [...content[0].matchAll(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/g)][0][0];
    if (table) {
      return [...table.matchAll(/<tr[\s\S\w]+?<\/tr>/g)].pop()[0].replace(/<[\w\s\S]+?>/g, "").replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    }
  }
  return "No value";
}
```

- This sample script returns the same result with above sample formula.

### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: to Perfection! Thank you!

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.